# How to change drag-n-drop cursor during drag operation based on condition of element it hovers over

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, cursor

The gist is that I want to change the drag-n-drop cursor based on a condition at the element it hovers over.  My understanding is that the drag cursor is based on a combination of `"effectAllowed"` at the source and `"dropEffect"` at the target.  I have set `effectAllowed="copy"` so the cursor indicates the data can be copied.  But based on certain conditions at the target, I may want the `dropEffect="none"` or `="copy"` at the target.  No matter what I do, I cannot get the cursor to display as `"none"` when it hovers over a target that I sometimes want to be a drop target and sometimes not.  I can prevent the data from dropping but I can't change the cursor so the user gets a visible cue.  I want the same effect that occurs when the cursor moves from a droppable zone to a non-droppable zone.

More detail: I am using HTML5 drag-n-drop.  I have a one-column table whose td elements are draggable and my ondragstart handler looks like this:

```
dragStartHandler(event){
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", $(event.target).text());
}
```

I have a two column table where the drop occurs.  The ondragover handler for these td elements simply runs `event.preventDefault()`.  However I have distinct ondragenter handlers for each column.  For the first column the ondragenter handler simply runs `event.preventDefault()`.   For the second column I have added

```
if (x) {event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";};
```

I have appropriate ondrop and ondragleave handlers and everything works great except for the ability to control the cursor.  I have read many other questions that want to change the cursor but I have not found one that is trying to change it during the drag operation based on a condition of the element it hovers over.  Is there a way to do this?